# Change the date format in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I am using a WordPress website and I want to change the date display format from 02/02/02 to 02.02.02. How should I do this?

```
<input type="text" name="deliverydate" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control input-custom input-custom--sm datetimepicker" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[_format_{field name} "{date format}"]`. You should read [documentation](https://contactform7.com/date-field/)